# Remove unwanted pattern in python regex from html string

Tags: python, regex

I have to parse the custom vin number from html

I get few wrong matched number also.

```
 .....
 <meta name="google-site-verification" content="l4du7Ao9MH6TM2nJ5L54qqWoXWcuOkdeqhXCADgKErc" />
 <meta name="msvalidate.01" content="FAD32C2469C51767894EB50068D37244" />
     .....
  <div class="hproduct auto chevrolet" data-classification="primary" data- vin="3GNDA23D18S647673" data-make="Chevrolet" >

 .....
 </dd></dl><dl class='vin'><dt>VIN:</dt><dd>3GNDA23D18S647673</dd></dl> <span 
 ....... etc....
```

This is the piece of html which contains required portion

When I apply my regex in python

```
import re
re.findall("([0-9A-Z]{8}[0-9xX]{1}[1-9A-Y^U]{1}[0-9A-Z]{2}[0-9]{5})",html)
```

I get the required results along with the unwanted data
like

```
['FAD32C2469C517678',
 '3GNDA23D18S647673',
 '3GNDA23D18S647673']
```

FAD32C2469C517678 is unwanted one.

How can I get rid of this unwanted patteren in regex in python?

Comment: Why not use an HTML parser instead?

Comment: [DON'T parse HTML with Regexes](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)

Comment: @fge Actually my requirement is to handle with uncertain html tags with different pages.So, I am using regex just take this string.Thanks for your reply.Yeah I am using Html parser "lxml" only for the parsing purpose with other data extractions.Here i wanted to check the count of this particular string.so I use various sources

Comment: If so, cannot you filter out what you are sure is uninteresting using lxml (I don't use it, so I don't know) so that the regex get more simple to write?

Comment: we can filter out in lxml but we have more different layout of html.So, using html parser we could do things sequentially instead of parallel.

Answer (score 3):

Please, use a parser:

```
import lxml.html as lh
doc=lh.fromstring(html)
doc.xpath('.//@vin')
```

**out**

```
["3GNDA23D18S647673"]
```

EDIT:
if vin is always an attribute, but you don't know the name, you can try:

```
doc.xpath('.//@*[string-length() = "17"]') # get's attrs with lenght 17
```

or with regex, if you really,really have to:

```
import re
re.findall('"([A-Z0-9]{17})"',html)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should really use an **HTML parser** but for a quick fix use the regexp `(?<=vin=")[^"]+`:

```
>>> import re
>>> html = """.....
...  <meta name="google-site-verification" content="l4du7Ao9MH6TM2nJ5L54qqWoXWcuOkdeqhXCADgKErc" />
...  <meta name="msvalidate.01" content="FAD32C2469C51767894EB50068D37244" />
...      .....
...   <div class="hproduct auto chevrolet" data-classification="primary" data- vin="3GNDA23D18S647673" data-make="Chevrolet" >
... 
...  .....
...  </dd></dl><dl class='vin'><dt>VIN:</dt><dd>3GNDA23D18S647673</dd></dl> <span 
...  ....... etc...."""

>>> re.findall('(?<=vin=")[^"]+',html)
['3GNDA23D18S647673']
```

This uses [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match `[^"]+` *(one or more characters not a double quote)* after the string after `vin="`.

If you want to more strict in your match you could use your regexp in combination with the positive lookbehind:

```
re.findall('(?<=vin=")[0-9A-Z]{8}[0-9xX]{1}[1-9A-Y^U]{1}[0-9A-Z]{2}[0-9]{5}',html)
['3GNDA23D18S647673']
```